# SMPS Control - Comparator in Sinking or Sourcing Configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, control, feedback

Tried something for fun: I modified a constant-current-output SMPS' feedback-control block which is in sinking configuration to sourcing configuration.

Here are the simplified schematics of the secondary side:

**Before:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2V6o0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**After:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMIYFL.png)</sup>

The circuit is not working in sourcing (latter) configuration. It works if I revert it back to the sinking (former) configuration.

Does it really make a difference? What can cause this "problem"? What may I have done wrong?

Comment: It looks like it should work Rohat.

Comment: What are the op-amp's power supply voltages?

Comment: @user253751 +15V, -5V.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, it should. I'm curious about if this relates to the sink/source drive capability of the opamp.